# Mongoose: Add new Schema property and update all current documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have at production a NodeJS application running using MongoDB and Mongoose, which inside has a Mongoose Schema like:

```
var Product = new Schema({
    "name": { type: String, required: true }
  , "description": { type: String }
});
```

Now, as a new requirement I'm adding a new property to the Schema at my local, like this:

```
var Product = new Schema({
    "name": { type: String, required: true }
  , "description": { type: String }
  , "isPublic": { type: Boolean, default: true }
});
```

When I restart my NodeJS process, I was expecting an update to all of my current documents (products), so now every document have a property `isPublic` which value is `true`.

What happened is no document has that new property and if I do a `someProduct.Save({ isPublic: true })` it gets added.

**Question**: is there a way to accomplish that?, 
I know I can do a $set from command line with mongo client, but I want to know if there is a way where Mongoose will add the missing property after the Schema changed on a process restart.

Answer (score 6):

> What happened is no document has that new property and if I do a `someProduct.Save({ isPublic: true })` it gets added.

That's because the mongoose `default` attribute works just for new documents. There're two workarounds:

- Write your code to treat documents without the `isPublic` property as `true`;
- Or, as you've mentioned above, set the property manually through mongodb console.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use MongoSH. Adding a new property to a Mongoose Schema will never update existing documents unless the programmer does it.

Use the updateMany command in the Mongo Shell (MongoSH):

```
// Get all documents in the collection, and set the field to a value
db.users.updateMany( {} , 
    { $set: {"newlyCreatedField": "defaultValue"} }
);
```